# Implementing some common ADTs with dynamic allocated arrays and realloc()

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

Of course every programmer has heard that implementing say a stack with an array has its disadvantages with the most one being the fixed size; but after learning about the realloc function it seems there exists a way to implement this kind of ADTs and others with a dynamically changing array like follows:

First I will dynamically allocate the first member of the array with the malloc function.
Then when I would like to add another member all I have to do is realloc the size to increase it and use array[n+1] = new item to add it.
Third if I want to delete the item I can again use the realloc function to shrink the dynamic array.

The benefits are (at least from my point of view) astonishing because you will have e.g. a stack with the benefits of a dynamically allocated storage and that of a normal array like random access and easy manipulation and so on.

To be honest I can’t really believe that this is feasible because if it was then why didn’t I read about it in any textbook or on the internet (it is not possible that I made here some kind of invention or so as I am actually still a novice).

So there must be something wrong I am not noticing and I am ready to hear it :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite see a question here (at least not a programming-related one).

Comment: My question: Is this kind of implementation really achievable or are there some kind of problems which make it impossible?

Comment: The huge disadvantage is the expense of reallocating the array every single time you add a new element. Most implementations will increase the array size by powers of two.

Comment: What do you mean by powers of two??

Comment: Functionally it works fine. But like most things in computing there is a tradeoff. `realloc` needs to find new memory and to copy the entire old memory to the new memory. That's the cost. Whether it is an acceptable cost depends on the context so there isn't a single right or wrong answer.

Comment: The other disadvantage of using realloc is that you need to come up with a policy of shrinking the array/stack size. Otherwise the stack memory will always be stuck at the high water mark which is a waste of memory resource.

Comment: So as I expected the really big problem is cost of copying the memory segments if there is no adjacent free memory. Are there any more problems?

Comment: @alan au Whats the problem with shrinking the array size I can use realloc again to shrik if I want?

Comment: As jacket alluded to, if you do a naieve implementation that grows the stack one entry at a time then you will need to do many `reallocs` In addition to the immediate cost of doing the alloc and copy, such an implementation is likely to result in memory fragmentation issues.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how expensive memory copying really is? I mean if anyone can give me some practical examples of the average cost of memory copying.

Comment: You don't need to know the absolute costs to do the analysis. Cause that system dependant. Imagine you have a stack of 1 million elements and you realloc every time an element is added or deleted. That's a copy of 1 million elements each time. Of course most people would not implement it like that but that's just giving an illustration of what the tradeoff consideratons are. For example, if the stack is always small then perhaps a fixed array allocation would work fine, for medium sized stacks perhaps a dynamic chunk sized realloc and for super large stacks perhaps a full dynamic linked list.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One critical issue with `realloc` is that it may or may not move the existing memory content to a new buffer, but if it does decide to do so it will do so using a byte-for-byte copy (ala `memcpy`).

In general, C++ objects are meant to be moved or copied using their move or copy constructors, and any objects in memory being deallocated should have their destructors invoked.  The `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` functions don't generally have any "hooks" to let the caller manage the object copying, so it's impractical for C++ libraries to use `realloc` for buffers storing arbitrary types of objects.

That said, `realloc` can be used for very simple objects for which `memcpy`-style movement is acceptable.  People do hack up container classes using `realloc` - just AFAIK such containers don't tend to be popular enough to have made it into major libraries, probably because the performance benefits are less than you might hope (it will depend on the proportion of times that `realloc` can resize in place, and e.g. `vector` has `reserve` and inbuilt doubling of capacity when resizing, which tends to limit copying costs).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use `std::vector` as the base for a `std::stack` type.

The `std::vector` automatically handles resizing and the space for its contents are allocated dynamically.

You should take a look at `std::stack`.  I do believe that `std::stack` handles memory allocations for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick answer to the question about whether it's possible:  yes, of course.

C++'s library has a `stack<>` data type that will use a `deque` for backing storage by default, but you can choose to use a `vector` instead if you really want a contiguous array to back the stack's storage.

Also, Sedgewick's "Algorithms, 4th Edition"  book discusses using an array and dynamic resizing to implement a stack in Chapter 1.

I'm sure there are innumerable implementations and discussions that can be found on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are asking about what the differences and drawbacks of fixed/dynamic array or linked list structures are in sense of stack implementation.

Fixed array is the easiest way if you know that your stack a) never exceeds some limit and b) is small enough to not consume too much memory (the amount depends on situation).

Dynamic array is allowed to be resized and has O(1) random access, but you have to implement exponential resizes and even then performance may suffer from excessive copying on reallocation. Realloc() has it's own overhead, so if you resize it on *each* insert/remove, performance may degrade very quickly. The usual scheme is to grow x1.5 or x2 and shrink on x0.5 or less. Heap fragmentation may be pretty high, especially with lots of stacks growing at the same time.

Linked list is a great option when you do not need random access and only operate on top-or-nearest values. It allows quick inserts with lesser heap fragmentation, as each list node is tiny, fixed in size and allocated separately. OTOH, you have slight malloc() overhead which is negligible with modern allocators.

Answer (score 1):

You're onto a reasonable track with a few tweaks to your idea.

You generally don't want to represent stacks using linked lists in performance-critical areas, as the cost of allocating/freeing each individual entry and the memory fragmentation that results can add up to a substantial overhead unless you combine that with an efficient fixed allocator that encourages contiguous results. Even then, when equipped with a very efficient O(1) fixed allocator, the increase in node size of storing list pointers for small objects can reduce cache hits considerably (ex: for a stack of 32-bit integers for a 64-bit system, we're now adding a 64-bit pointer per entry and possibly additional structure padding for alignment).

Yet you don't want to pay for the cost of a `realloc` either every time you insert a new element, and if your stack is to be used to store C++ objects, it is quite awkward to use `realloc` as it may create a new memory block in a new location and fail to invoke destructors for the C++ elements stored in the old one as well as copy constructors for the elements transferred to the new block in addition to bulldozing over vtables. So most people don't bother with `realloc` in C++, since it unfortunately lacks that type information to work with to make that safe to use with C++ objects.

But where you do have a good start is that a high-performance stack is going to involve a fairly contiguous structure to avoid that linked list overhead. One basic tweak to your idea is to store an additional integral tracking `capacity` in addition to the size of the stack. When you push to the stack, check if the size exceeds capacity, and if so, increase the capacity by some factor (ex: double it) and allocate a new array with the new capacity and transfer elements to it (can use `realloc` here if the elements are not C++ objects).

Another thing you can do is combine the idea of a linked list and array into an *unrolled linked list* where each node stores K elements: basically arrays linked together. This way you're only paying for the linked overhead every K elements instead of for each element and typically getting much better cache performance as a result of the improved contiguity.